# NoClassDefFoundError with StringUtils in a jax-ws context

Tags: java, maven, jax-ws, jboss-eap-6

StringUtils class (and so on org.apache.commons-lang3) is not available at runtime.

Here is my config :

```
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

   @Inject
   private MyEndpoint myEndpoint;


   /**
     * @return Endpoint
     */
    @Bean
    public Endpoint importDasWsEndpoint() {
        Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create("/myEndpoint", myEndpoint);
        return endpoint;
    }

}
```

The application is loaded with a WebApplicationInitializer:

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

   @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(AppWebConfig.class);
      rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
   }
}
```

Here is the dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
15:54:07,636 ERROR [org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.InvocationHandlerJAXWS] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBAS015594: Invocation de méthode échouée avec pour exception : org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.webservices.deployers.WSComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(WSComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:49)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185) [jboss-as-ee-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.webservices.invocation.AbstractInvocationHandler.invoke(AbstractInvocationHandler.java:129)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.performInvocation(JBossWSInvoker.java:177)
at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:237) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:69) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.JBossWSInvoker.invoke(JBossWSInvoker.java:146)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:107) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) [cxf-api-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-rt-core-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.2.3.jar:2.2.3]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:97)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.transport.ServletHelper.callRequestHandler(ServletHelper.java:131)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:88)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.service(CXFServletExt.java:136)
at org.jboss.wsf.spi.deployment.WSFServlet.service(WSFServlet.java:140) [jbossws-spi-2.3.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-2]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.5.11.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.11.Final-redhat-1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
```

What's missing in my configuration ?

Comment: Do you have commons-lang3 jar in the resulting war?

Comment: And no, after checking it, it was not included in the resulting war. But it appears (on Eclipse) in the maven dependencies.

Comment: Issue resolved : changed the scope of commons-lang3 in the parent pom, from "provided" to "compile".